# How to disable dynamicBoost in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Let's say I have 2 entities Book and BookReview, there are certain times when I want to return a set of books with the highest review, and there are times when I just want a random set of books.

So far I understand that even though the strategy can be dynamic but the DynamicBoost is explicitly annotated. Therefore it always apply on the hibernate-search query processing that entity?

An example from hibernate search:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@DynamicBoost(impl = VIPBoostStrategy.class)
public class Person {
    private PersonType type;

    // ...
}

public class VIPBoostStrategy implements BoostStrategy {
    public float defineBoost(Object value) {
        Person person = ( Person ) value;
        if ( person.getType().equals( PersonType.VIP ) ) {
            return 2.0f;
        }
        else {
            return 1.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

For example if I have a second DynamicBoost strategy for the BookReview entity, let's say for most number of reviews. How can I achieved that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DynamicBoost is about *index-time* boosting, i.e. about storing the boost along with the indexed document. So there can only be one boost per field per document.

Also, note that @DynamicBoost [is in the process of being deprecated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.8/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-dynamic-boost).

Regardless, I think you're trying too hard to use boosting. Boosting is mostly useful when sorting by full-text relevance score. Lucene (and thus Hibernate Search) is perfectly capable of sorting scalar data without using boosts.

If you need to sort by the number of reviews, just add a "numberOfReview" field to your mapping:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Person {
    private PersonType type;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    @javax.persistence.Transient
    @Field
    public int getNumberOfReviews() {
        return reviews.size();
    }
    // ...
}
```

... and then sort by this field:

```
QueryBuilder qb = /* the usual */;
FullTextQuery query = /* the usual */;
query.sort( qb.sort().byField( "numberOfReviews" ).desc().createSort() );
```

Same goes with any value you could possibly want to sort by.

What's interesting is that, **when using an explicit sort**, the full-text relevance score is ignored, and thus the **dynamic boosting is ignored**. Which seems to be part of what you're looking for... ?

Note that, if you're using an older version of Hibernate Search, the sort builder might not be available and then you'll have to use a custom-built Lucene Sort. Both methods of building sorts are explained in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#__a_id_query_sorting_a_sorting

Comment: You are right I think I've gone too obsessed with DynamicBoosting that I thought it would be better to use it. But anyway I'm dropping it off in favor of the much easier sort().